# Iterate over nested JSON objects and append data to variable

Tags: javascript, lodash

i'm pretty new with JS and i'm struggling a little bit with iterating over a nested JSON object.

I need to grab the value of each nested `Node_Subtask_Success` in `history` and save that to a variable I can access later.

The dataset is rather large so I won't add it directly into this post, but i've uploaded it to pastebin here: https://pastebin.com/puZ77V0K

What i've tried so far:

```
updateData: function() {
                axios
                .get('http://localhost/api/node/839b6556940b19cf9651d0ff7ed08c1154d42b8ef2ef0bda92ffd188d9c82aa0600504389a10f54429c6f83d8cfd58c3e9be1598a4592f37ddd8cd3b3adb9cba')
                .then((response) => {
                    _.each(response.data, function(node) {
                      for(var num in response.data.history) {
                        console.log(num.Node_Subtask_Success)
                      }
                    });
                })
            },
```

But the above just prints undefined 269 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason behind that is [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) will pick up the property name in that way:

> The `for...in` statement iterates over all enumerable properties of an object that are keyed by strings (ignoring ones keyed by Symbols), including inherited enumerable properties.

What you can do instead:

```js
const history = [
  {
      "id": 539,
      "Node_Cores": 1,
      "Node_Subtask_Success": 856,
  }
];

history.forEach(e => {
   console.log(e.Node_Subtask_Success);
});
```

See an example why it was not working:

```js
const history = [
  {
      "id": 539,
      "Node_Cores": 1,
      "Node_Subtask_Success": 856,
  }
];

for (var num in history) {
  console.log({num}); // this return 0
  console.log(num.Node_Subtask_Success); // this one undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to iterate over the `history` array, so you should do that and only that. You don't need multiple iterations here.

```js
updateData: function() {
                axios
                .get('http://localhost/api/node/839b6556940b19cf9651d0ff7ed08c1154d42b8ef2ef0bda92ffd188d9c82aa0600504389a10f54429c6f83d8cfd58c3e9be1598a4592f37ddd8cd3b3adb9cba')
                .then((response) => {
                    _.each(response.data.history, function(node) {
                        console.log(num.Node_Subtask_Success)
                    });
                })
            },
```

If you want to do it using vanilla JavaScript:

```js
updateData: function() {
                axios
                .get('http://localhost/api/node/839b6556940b19cf9651d0ff7ed08c1154d42b8ef2ef0bda92ffd188d9c82aa0600504389a10f54429c6f83d8cfd58c3e9be1598a4592f37ddd8cd3b3adb9cba')
                .then((response) => {
                    for(hist in response.data.history) {
                        console.log(hist.Node_Subtask_Success)
                    });
                })
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it seems that you are doing a loop in a loop. `_.each` ([see lodash docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#forEach)) iterate over an array. You iterate over `response.data` which is an Object, not an array.

You should iterate over `response.data.history` instead. Like this

```
updateData: function() {
    axios.get('http://localhost/api/node/839b6556940b19cf9651d0ff7ed08c1154d42b8ef2ef0bda92ffd188d9c82aa0600504389a10f54429c6f83d8cfd58c3e9be1598a4592f37ddd8cd3b3adb9cba')
    .then((response) => {
        _.each(response.data.history, (historyElement) => {
            //your element here
            console.log(historyElement.Node_Subtask_Success)
        });

};
```